# Join Pandas Dataframe to Shapefile?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, pandas

I have a shapefile:

```
Street1    Street2    Street3
Field      Clark      Taylor
Field      Jackson    State
Franklin   23rd       25th
```

And a Dataframe `df`:

```
Page    Entry_Date
12      08012018
17      07252018
11      07252018
```

The only commonalities between the two are the index position of the rows. I'd like to join them together so my result is as below in my shapefile

```
Street1    Street2    Street3    Page    Entry_Date
Field      Clark      Taylor     12      08012018
Field      Jackson    State      17      07252018
Franklin   23rd       25th       11      07252018
```

I've tried a couple ways but it doesn't seem that `arcpy` likes to cooperate with `pandas`

```
in_shp = "C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Proj56\\ExportShp.shp"

for idx, row in df.itterrows():
    arcpy.JoinField_management(in_shp, "FID", df, idx, [df.columns.values])
```

This just gives me an error. Is there any way to incorporate a `pandas` dataframe into an existing shapefile without completely rewriting everything?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think arcpy has any kind of pandas integration.  It does have some functions to work with numpy arrays, which is what pandas uses on the backend.  Pull out a numpy array, use arcpy.NumPyArrayToTable(), and join that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those curious, I converted the `dataframe` into a `numpy` `array` and then stored the table `in_memory`, joined my records, then exported out back to a shapefile. Not the cleanest workaround but a workaround all the same.

```
x = np.array(np.rec.fromrecords(df.values))
names = df.dtypes.index.tolist()
x.dtype.names = tuple(names)
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(x, "in_memory/mytable")
...
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("in_memory/mytable", OutFolder, "NewShp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to export the data frame to a scratch csv file using df.to_csv(filepath) then use the arcpy.JoinField_management tool to join the scratch csv file to the shapefile, and finally delete the scratch file (or not).